# elasticsearch searching where nth character of a field matches the parameter

Tags: elasticsearch

Elasticsearch index has json docs like this

```
{
  id: ABC120379013
  name: Matlo Jonipa
  jobs: {nested data}
}
```

When defining index schema, I register id as keyword.

Now I need to write a query that can return all docs where 4th char in the id field value is digit 9.

```
# matched docs
id: ABC920379013,
id: Zxr900013000
...
```

I have two questions for this usecase.

1- Am I indexing it right when I set id as a keyword field? I feel I should be using some analyzer but I don't know which one.

2- Can someone guide me how to write a query to match nth char of a field?

I can use this regex to match a string whose 4th character is 9 but can I use it in an elasticsearch query?

```
/^...9.*$/
or
/^.{3}9.*$/
```

Answer (score 1):

Below query would help your use case. I've used [Script Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-query.html).

Also, yes you are doing it right, you need to make sure that the field `id` would be of type `keyword`. Note that `keyword` type doesn't make use of `analyzers`.

```
POST regexindex/_search
{
  "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : {
                "script" : {
                    "script" : {
                        "source": "doc['id'].value.indexOf('9') == 3",
                        "lang": "painless"
                     }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've mentioned `.indexOf('9') == 3` because index starts from `0`

Comment: Did this meet your requirements? Are you specifically looking only for regex only based solution?